# What is the meaning of はずでしょう

Tags: grammar, meaning, song-lyrics

I was listening to a song and the following lyrics came up:

> 試されていくはずでしょう

Does combining はず+でしょう just strengthen the "must be, probably" idea or is there some other meaning?

I interpret this as something like "It "must probably" going to be tested/tried". I know it sounds a bit off, but is it something along these lines?

[Song](https://youtu.be/2PsK1IuQXhY):

> いくつもの声が
> この空を超えて
> 輝いてまた消えるよ
> 戸惑いの中で
> ただ意味を求め
> **試されてゆくはずでしょう**
>
> ひらひらひら ひらひらひら 落ちるように
> 嬉しいこと 悲しいこと
> 全て抱いて生きてきた

Answer (score 1):

Basically, `～はずでしょう` can only be natural when it is an interrogative.

Assuming the sentence is a question (though the question mark is missing as it's lyrics), `試されてゆくはずでしょう？` is meaning "It must be tested in the future, right?".

If it's a declarative sentence, its meaning is ambiguous since the usage is unusual. However, it might be interpreted as being equivalent to `試されてゆくはずだ` (here `でしょう` is considered to be used as a substitute for `だ` to enhance its lyricism).

Answer (score 1):

試されてゆく means "it will be put to multiple trials as time goes by", and はずだ means "it must be". "でしょう" is added to enhance the belief or desire of the author in a feminine way. E.g. if you say 必ずくる vs. 必ずくるでしょう, then they both mean "they will for sure come", but the former sounds a lot more masculine and 勇ましい, whereas 必ずくるでしょう sounds feminine.

E.g you can shout 必ずくる! but shouting 必ずくるでしょう! is a bit odd (or at least more reserved).